# How do I fix the shelf support holes in my cabinets?

Tags: cabinets, shelving

In my pantry cabinet, the holes for the plastic brackets has gotten too large and they do not hold. The cabinets are made out of particle board. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show a closeup well focused picture of the damaged hole area and a picture of the plastic bracket?

Answer (score 5):

The metric (4 or 5mm) holes can be redrilled to hold the 1/4" shelf spoons. If that does not do it, there are metal sockets for the 1/4" spoons that take a slightly larger hole, then they can be driven into place to hold the larger spoon. 
If the spoons or clips already have a 1/4" hole, then you may be better off retro fitting a shelf track system. Third pic.

Instead of trying to drive nails in a tight space, use 4ga X3/4" screws instead, the cabinet will thank you for it.

[image]     [image]   [image]

The picture size is grossly out of proportion, buit the first pic is the socket that holds the spoon which is the second pic. The socket looks more like a bucket, that will hold 10 of those spoons..

Comment: When I search for shelf track system, I get the kind where the long supports stick out, not ones that hold these square supports. What do I search for? Or do you have a link to the ones in the photo?

Comment: @Merlin-they-them- I just did a fast search for "KV track", it shows the various supports the company makes

Answer (score 3):

You could also drill out a much larger hole (3/4" seems good to me) and glue in a wooden (non-particle board) plug. After the glue is dried, drill the proper size hole in the plug.

Comment: I have plugged holes like Ecnerwal suggests in the past it creates a very strong hole.+ , I have not tried the metal rings that Jack showed but those may be easier if the hole is not two large.+

Answer (score 0):

Redrill a new hole 3/4" away from the bad hole and fill the old hole with Seamfillor cover it with a vinyl Fastcap.

Answer (score -2):

I think toggle bolts...they are made to grab behind board (wall board etc.) that  has too big holes.